# What sort of computations Coretime is goin to do?

Tags: polkadot

As far as I know, on the Polkadot 2.0 update, a new feature called Coretime will be implemented on the Relaychain. It is something like the AWS lambda function execution where users have to pay for the deligated computation using Dot. Is it true? what sort of computations will be done in the future? How is the process of that computation, is it process distributed to some nodes or, does only one node process all the computation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details are still being hashed out but I would encourage you to read the RCF for agile coretime:

- https://github.com/polkadot-fellows/RFCs/blob/main/text/0001-agile-coretime.md

> It is something like the AWS lambda function execution where users have to pay for the deligated computation using Dot. Is it true?

With instantaneous coretime yes. You can think of as on-demand parachains, where as with bulk coretime, you can think of similar to what we have where a parachain commits to an extended lease.

> what sort of computations will be done in the future? How is the process of that computation, is it process distributed to some nodes or, does only one node process all the computation?

Other than the current parachain model, where you build a parachain and purchase coretimem, there is also discussion of building a more adhoc model of computation similar to what you're familiar with (lamdba functions on AWS). It is called Corejam. The details of it are still being worked on. You can start by reading here:

- https://github.com/polkadot-fellows/RFCs/pull/31

Comment: I hope to see the day an alternative to AWS Lamda function service which is not owned by any centralized institution

Comment: That would be the day when you know web3 has succeeded.